# Crop image upload using cropperjs plugins

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I tried to implement crop image upload plugins **CropperJS**. When I click on CropImage Button Maybe from reload, data will reset, but it shouldn't and all uploaded data should be ready for submission.

```js
// Initialize CropperJS
let cropper;

// Handle Image Input Change
document.getElementById('photo_of_mate').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let files = e.target.files;
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    // Display image in modal
    document.getElementById('cropper-image').src = reader.result;
    // Show modal
    document.getElementById('crop-modal').style.display = 'block';
    // Initialize CropperJS
    cropper = new Cropper(document.getElementById('cropper-image'), {
      aspectRatio: 1,
      viewMode: 1,
    });
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
});

// Handle Crop Confirm Button Click
document.getElementById('crop-confirm').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Get cropped image data
  let croppedDataUrl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/png');
  // Set src of cropped image tag
  document.getElementById('cropped-image').src = croppedDataUrl;
  // Display cropped image tag
  document.getElementById('cropped-image').style.display = 'block';
  // Set value of cropped image filename input tag
  document.getElementById('cropped-image-filename').value = 'cropped-image.png';
  // Hide modal
  document.getElementById('crop-modal').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.13/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.13/cropper.min.js"></script>
<div class="g-signup-form-area">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">

        <div class="g-signup-main">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4 class="text-white">Registration Form</h4>
          </div>
          <form action="">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="name_of_mate">Name 0f Mate</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="name_of_mate" placeholder="Name Of Mate">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="photo_of_mate">Photograph of Mate</label>
                <input type="file" name="" class="form-control" id="photo_of_mate">

                <!--                 Display Cropped Image -->
                <img id="cropped-image" src="" style="display:none;">

                <!-- Display Cropped Image Filename -->
                <!--                <input id="cropped-image-filename" type="text" readonly>-->


                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal" id="crop-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h2>Crop Image</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div id="cropper-container">
                        <img id="cropper-image" src="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button id="crop-confirm" class="btn">Confirm Crop</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <!--                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="photo_of_mate" name="photo_of_mate" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" onchange="validateImage(this)">-->
                <!--                <small class="text-danger error" id="error"></small>-->
                <!--                <input class="form-control" type="file" name=""  placeholder="Name Of Mate" required>-->
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="name_of_department">Name Of Department</label>
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="name_of_department">
                  <option selected>Select Department</option>
                  <option value="">Bangla</option>
                  <option value="">English</option>
                  <option value="">Economics</option>
                  <option value="">Political Science</option>
                  <option value="">Public Administration</option>
                  <option value="">Islamic History & Culture</option>
                  <option value="">Fine Arts</option>
                  <option value="">Sociology</option>
                  <option value="">History</option>
                  <option value="">Islamic Studies</option>
                  <option value="">Philosophy</option>
                  <option value="">Arabic</option>
                  <option value="">Pali</option>
                  <option value="">Physics</option>
                  <option value="">Chemistry</option>
                  <option value="">Botany</option>
                  <option value="">Zoology</option>
                  <option value="">Mathematics</option>
                  <option value="">Statistics</option>
                  <option value="">Marine Science & Fisheries</option>
                  <option value="">Forestry</option>
                  <option value="">Accounting BBA</option>
                  <option value="">Management BBA</option>
                  <option value="">Public Finance BBA</option>
                  <option value="">Marketing BBA</option>
                  <option value="">Accounting</option>
                  <option value="">Management</option>
                  <option value="">Marketing</option>
                  <option value="">Public Finance</option>

                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="contact_number">Contact Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="" id="contact_number" placeholder="Contact number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="email_address">Email Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="" id="email_address" placeholder="Email Address">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="home_district">Home District</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="home_district" placeholder="Home District">
              </div>


              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="occupation">Occupation</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="occupation" placeholder="Occupation">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="designation">Designation</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="designation" placeholder="Designation">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="blood_group">Blood Group</label>
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="blood_group">
                  <option selected value="A+">A+</option>
                  <option value="A-">A-</option>
                  <option value="B+">B+</option>
                  <option value="B-">B-</option>
                  <option value="O+">O+</option>
                  <option value="O-">O-</option>
                  <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                  <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="permanent_address">Permanent Address</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="" id="permanent_address" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="text-white" for="present_address">Present Address</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="" id="present_address" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="text-center">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-50">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>


        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```